# <more-routing> in Polymer is causing problems with route params

Tags: routes, polymer, web-component

I have a single page application with route config as follows :

```
<more-route name="projects" path="/projects">
    <more-route name="projectroot" path="/noProjectSelected"></more-route>
    <more-route name="projectname" path="/:projectname">
        <more-route name="edittask" path="/edit/:task"></more-route>
        <more-route name="newtask" path="/newtask"></more-route>
    </more-route>
</more-route>
```

Now I have a custom element with the following `more-route-selector` tag

```
<more-route-selector flex vertical layout>
    <core-pages flex vertical layout>
        <projects-view route="projects" flex></projects-view>
        <section route="search">
            <div>Search Page</div>
        </section>
        <section route="calendar">
            <div>Calendar Page</div>
        </section>
        <section route="settings">
            <div>Settings Page</div>
        </section>
        </core-pages>
</more-route-selector>
```

In `projects-view` element, I have another `more-route-selector` just to display the nested pages. The code for that is as follows :

```
<more-route-selector selectedParams="{{params}}" flex fullbleed vertical layout>
    <core-pages flex fullbleed vertical layout>
        <div route="projectroot" flex>Hello</div>
        <task-list projectname="{{params.projectname}}" route="projectname" flex></task-list>
        <add-modify-task processType="add" projectname="{{params.projectname}}" route="newtask" flex></add-modify-task>
        <add-modify-task processType="modify" projectname="{{params.projectname}}" task="task" route="edittask" flex></add-modify-task>
    </core-pages>
</more-route-selector>
```

The problem is that the console shows me following error : `Exception caught during observer callback: TypeError: Cannot read property 'projectname' of undefined`. I know that I need to pass in that `projectname` param. But I do not have that param at that time.

I want it to show `route=projectroot` section by default. Is there something in my code that I am doing wrong? Is there any way I can get rid of the error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can override navigateTo method and provide missing parameters.

```
 var oldnavigate = MoreRouting.Route.prototype.navigateTo;
            MoreRouting.Route.prototype.navigateTo = function (params) {
                if (this.fullPath.indexOf(":projectname") >= 0) {
                    if (params == null) {
                        params = {};
                    }
                    params.projectname = getDefaultProjectName();
                }
                return oldnavigate.call(this, params);
            };
```